# Remove trailing spaces from first field only

Tags: sed, awk, tr

I have a multi-lined, tab-delimited file like this:

99999**bbbbb**t999999**bb**t99t99t99t99

(where **b**=spaces, t=tabs)

Trailing spaces in the 2nd field are ok, but the trailing spaces in the 1st field need to be removed.
Is there an easy way to remove the trailing spaces from just the 1st field of each line? sed/awk/tr?

Comment: @Stéphane Chazelas
Thank you!, This was driving me crazy.
The TAB=; s/ *$TAB/$TAB/ worked perfectly, and removed only the spaces before the first tab (only first field).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sed $'s/ *\t/\t/' < file
```

would remove the spaces before the first tab. Here assuming a shell like ksh93, bash, zsh, mksh or FreeBSD sh with support for `$'...'` (which is scheduled for inclusion in issue 8 of the Single UNIX Specification).

Some `sed` implementations like GNU `sed` also recognise those `\t` directly:

```
sed 's/ *\t/\t/' file
```

Otherwise, POSIXly, you can do:

```
TAB=$(printf '\t')
sed "s/ *$TAB/$TAB/" file
```

You can also do the same with `awk` POSIXly:

```
awk '{sub(/ *\t/, "\t"); print}'
```

Comment: Why not `'s/  *//'`

Comment: @Costas, that would remove spaces at the beginning of the line which is not what was asked for AFAICT.